# Cannot stop widget resize with using a ConstrainedBox in Flutter Linux platform

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to prevent user to resize the app window under certain limits and use ConstrainedBox for this purpose. It works for max values (like maxWidth), but it doesn't work for min values (like minWidth). It is maybe working about interaction with other widgets, but it does not prevent window resize. I even can drop width of the app window to 1px.

How can I prevent that? I've seen some window size solutions for Windows platform via plugins but would prefer a way without a plugin.

Here's a simple example code. It's the default Flutter app with deleted comments and added ConstrainedBox.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 500),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
              Text(
                '$_counter',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution for the Linux platform. It could look like a little bit hacky, therefore I'll not accept my own answer for some time to wait for a more elegant solution.

Here's what I've done. Opened `linux/my_application.cc` file and added following lines just before `gtk_window_set_default_size(window, 1280, 720);` line.

```c
GdkGeometry hints;
hints.min_width = 350;
hints.min_height = 700;

gtk_window_set_geometry_hints(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIDGET(window), &hints, GDK_HINT_MIN_SIZE);
```

Since Flutter uses GTK on Linux, I've used related geometry limit method for the framework. It sets only the minimum values for the window right now, but you can add max values, too.